# SQL Server - Add Constraint for existing table using Alter Table function

Tags: sql-server-2008, alter-table, check-constraints, isnumeric, charindex

I got a little trouble with SQL. This is the table Customers :

```
ID      Name     Address                Phone
KP001   Bill     Jl Bali NO 27          81976524451
KP002   Jane     Jl Sandang NO 5        81876537521
KP003   Dion     Jl Kebon Jeruk NO 7    81684234913
```

the original structure table Customer :

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
ID char(5)primary key not null,
Name varchar(20),
Address varchar(30),
Phone varchar(12),
constraint cs2 check (LEN(ID)=5),
constraint cs3 check (ID like 'KP[0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
)
```

and I want to change table structure using Alter Table. I want to Add constraint to table Customers which Address after the 'no' must be a number.

First, in Indonesia there are street names using the 'NO' as an indicator street number. And requires the Customer table after the 'NO' is a number. I've tried with this query :

```
ALTER TABLE Customers WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT cs_address 
CHECK (CHARINDEX('no',Address)>1 AND
ISNUMERIC ( SUBSTRING (Address,7,2)) =1)
```

I know the query incorrect, but can you help me to fix the error and get the right results?

*sorry if my english is not good

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to validate the Address to always start with `NO`, followed by a numeric value, then

```
ALTER TABLE Customers WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT cs_address
CHECK
(
        CHARINDEX('no', Address) >= 1 
    AND ISNUMERIC(LTRIM(RTRIM
                (SUBSTRING (Address, CHARINDEX('no', Address) + 2, 7)))) = 1
)
```

Comment: Oh! So, if you want to allow addresses that contain "NO" but need not start with it, then please see the updated answer, @cindy.

Comment: I just try that query but i got the problem. If i insert with value 'Jalan Jakarta NO 10' than show messages : The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint.  I think it because before the word 'NO'. But i want is, when i insert with value 'Jalan Jakarta NO 10' it should be executed

Comment: sorry if I misunderstood, but where i can see the updated answer? @vikdor

Comment: Oh, OK. But i get message : Cannot find the object "Address" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
what should i do?

Comment: Address is supposed to be your column name! @cindy

Comment: my mistake :p. that query was successful .Thank you very much Vikdor :)